# How to pass request type as an argument to retrofit API

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

This is how i define methods in API interface of retrofit.

```
@POST
@Headers("platform: Android")
Call<JsonObject> getRegisterUserData(
        @Url String url,
        @Header("User-Agent") String userAgent,
        @Header("x-dsn") String dsn,
        @Header("x-appversion") String appVersion,
        @Body JsonObject jsonObject
);
```

I want to know any possibility to pass request type `GET` or `POST` as a a parameter to a method, instead of passing it as an annotation.

Comment: this is the functionality of the library to work with GET/POST type request dear, can you can actually tell your requirement?

Comment: @quicklearner: I have a networkUtility class that deals with retrofit, this class takes `Url`, `JsonObect` and other parameters as argument, now there are some `GET` and `POST` url's , so i want to pass request type from the activity class as a method argument. e.g: `networkUtility.call(POST, "url", jsonObject)`

Comment: why dont you create two method for GET and POST and call them when u need , rather than passing in call method